# Defining a scale number from the Helmert transformation

Tags: georeferencing, coordinate-system, scale, similarity

I know this is more bit of a cartographic issue, but maybe somebody would be able to help. I have an old map georeferenced to the openstreetmap with 50 identical points. I want to get the scale of the old map.

I am using Helmert 4-parameter tranformation (similarity) with the equations:
*X=ax-by+X0*
*Y=ay+bx+Y0*
where *x* and *y* are the old map coordinates in meters (same as coordinates used from openstreetmap), *X0* and *Y0* are translations and then there is one scaling and rotation.

Scaling parameter *m* could be obtained as:
*m=sqrt(a^2+b^2)*
Rotation is:
*alpha=arctan(b/a)*

The resolution of the old map is 400 dpi (0.0635 mm per pixel).

I have all the parameters counted now with the least squares method.
Does anybody know how to get the scale of the old map from these parameters? I want the scale in a common form 1 : M (1 : 600 000).
*EDIT*: Further on I will use iteratively reweighted least squares and I will be omitting those identical points with the biggest spatial error (I am working with very old maps which have mistakes). I will do this to make the definition of scale more accurate. That's why I need to use the transformation parameters for the map scale definition and not only to compare the distances.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: One of the properties of your georeferenced map should be cell size, or the ground distance length/width of a pixel in whatever CRS you're using. If you know the mapped size of one pixel, and you know the image of the orginal map was at 400 pixels per inch, then 400 * cell size = ground distance, so the original map scale is 1 (inch) : ground distance.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. You have an answer from @ChrisW above and another from me below. Unless we misunderstand something, notice we both ignore your similarity transformation, as it seems unrelated to the actual (simple-seeming) question. If you need to clarify things, please do so via the **[edit]** button.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. I'm sorry I should have been more specific before. I need to use the transformation parameters because I want to make the map scale the most accurate and I don't want to rely on the map drawing itself in only one particular area. (@martinf I made the edit to the question)

Comment: I'm still finding it hard to see how the transformation scale parameter is going to help -- unless it is from *map* units/distance to *ground* units/distance and in which case it gives you your answer directly. What *are* your helmert parameters? (Again, editing the Q is best.)

Comment: @martinf In this transformation I have two translations, one scaling and one rotation. I have map coordinates in meters and ground coordinates from openstreetmap in meters as well. However the scaling parameter obtained from the equation isn't the one used in classic 1:M ratio.

Comment: Under that approach you are saying the original map has no scale or it varies. No straight formula will give a single scale because rather than a fixed ratio it is a continuous surface type of data - scale between any two given points will vary depending on sample location. You would have to take *n* samples and work some statistics to determine a mean/average/approximate scale. But it sounds to me like you're trying to calculate *distortion*, not scale. A map is either to scale or not - mapping errors are a whole other issue.

Comment: @ChrisW Well there is a scale written on a map and I want to somehow evaluate if is accurate or not. According to how many and which identical points I use I also get different values or parameters in the Helmert transformation. And I thought that with the knowledge of the scaling parameter, measure units and maybe resolution of the old map I should be able to define the map scale. Which naturally will differ as well when I use other set of identical points. I am sorry if I am wrongly describing the issue. I might be using bad vocabulary.

Comment: The problem is the *scale* may be accurate but the *mapping* may not be. At this point I'm going to say you're definitely looking at distortion and not scale, and any accuracy measurement you're doing is on the *transformation* and not the actual map. And we won't even get into scan introduced distortion. I suggest taking a look at [this help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t000000mn000000) and perhaps a look at the [Wiki on Helmert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmert_transformation) (particularly the Restrictions section).

Comment: And remember: it is possible that your "old" map is more accurate than OSM! Another consideration: all maps have scale distortion, as an inevitable result of *map projection* from the curved globe to the flat map.

Comment: @ChrisW I might be using the affine transformation as well. Which should give me two scaling parameters in two directions of the axis. I may be misusing the word "scale" because in my language it has the similar meaning as distortion. We could say that I am working with the accuracy of the transformation but its accuracy depends on the points I am using or? So simply you think I can't use the parameter of the transformation (distortion?) to get the map scale in a sense 1:M as a ratio used on paper maps.

Comment: Interesting thing is that I tried the transformation with different ground coordinates. Instead of openstreetmap I used coordinate system used in our country only (in meters as well). I got different values of the transformation parameters. And the scaling parameter (distortion?) is now very similar to the map scale which is written on the map. So I am a bit confused now :/

Comment: Correct - transformation will not yield map scale in the ratio sense as on paper. Maps are a 2D representation of a 3D surface by means of [projection](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/documentation/ao_/710Understanding_Map_Projections.pdf). **All** projections distort in four ways - shape, area, direction, and distance (or scale as you are asking). Various projections minimize distortion in some ways at the cost of increasing it in the rest. A highly localized CRS will have less distortion in a given area than one made for a larger area because there is less potential error to account for.

Comment: @ChrisW Yes, I think I know what you mean. And I was trying to minimize the influence of distortion as I say to Martin underneath. I will try to give another detail. I am also working with the SW [MapAnalyst](http://mapanalyst.org/) which is doing cartometric analysis of raster maps after collecting the identical points. It is using the Helmert transformation as well and one of the output is the "map scale". This ratio is similar to the one written on map and differ when I choose more/less/different points. I would like to be able to do the same.

Comment: The scale that software is giving is a statistical global approximation. Per my second comment, by that point the software is treating scale as a continuos varying surface and not a fixed value. This is clearly explained on one of [their pages](http://mapanalyst.org/examples/exisolines.html). The number being given is statistically derived from transformation *results* (not formulas), and will therefore vary depending on the input control points.

Comment: @ChrisW Sorry for bothering you that much. What do you mean by transformation results? I know that the SW could show scale isolines but it also shows a report of the computation where the _m Scale Factor_ term is used and which made me think I should be able to obtain it as well. See the [prinscreen](http://oi60.tinypic.com/2hguzup.jpg). This number (520354) corresponds with the scale on the map.

Comment: Not a bother at all. Read the heading of that section in your report - "Transformation parameters and standard deviations **computed with 50 points**." It also gives a stat of +/- approximately 4430. It computed the distance between those pairs of points, then averaged those resulting scale values to arrive at a global scalefactor to use in the transformation. Paper A to B = x, ground A to B = y and x:y = scalefactor. In this case average x:y is 'close' to the given scale on the map, so the map scale is 'accurate' in that CRS (perhaps the paper map uses the same projection).

Comment: @ChrisW Ok then I was wrong probably. I thought that the number mentioned there as _m Scale Factor_ could have been gained from the equations above where _m_ appears together with other parameters.  
My own results from the transformation differ btw. a lot also in other parameters. Translation is completely different, so maybe MapAnalyst is using different coordinates origin than me (I use map and ground coordinates exported from this SW so results should be the same).

Comment: The last message had been sent earlier than I studied the MapAnalyst documentation properly. The SW really does a procedure of projections to remove the distortion as it is described [here](http://mapanalyst.org/man/openstreetmap.html). Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

As a unitless ratio,

```
map scale = map length / ground length
```

(assuming lengths are in same units)

Expressed in the conventional form, `1: M`,

```
M = 1 / map scale 
  = ground length / map length
```

So, calculate the ground distance between two of your control points, measure the distance between the same two points on the old map, and (assuming the distances are in same units) divide one by the other. If your map measurement is in different units (not meters), first convert it to meters.

Note that this classic notion of map scale only makes sense if you have a printed or displayed map upon which you can measure distances. If this (digital) map gives you equivalent ground distances directly, then there is no ratio scale.

---

If, as you say, you are estimating, by least squares, the *transformation scale* between two coordinate systems (or two maps), then this represents, *not* the map-to-ground scale, but the system-to-system scale (or map-to-map distortion), as Chris says. A different kind of scale.

---

If you are trying to estimate the *accuracy* of the old map, and *if* you can assume the OpenStreets map is accurate, then you *can* use the results of your least squares helmert transformation analysis:

Each of your control points will have *residuals* -- difference between before and after adjustment values -- within the old coordinate system. These give an indication of accuracy. As you state, some of those are very large and you *might* consider removing them. (Be careful though; using all reasonable data is more realistic than cherry-picking only some.) An overall measure of accuracy would then be the "root mean square" (RMS) value.

Comment: I will be using RMS value surely too. But the map scale is one of my necessary output. However I am now maybe a bit more familiarized with the terms scale and distortion. So the distortion would be different when using the different coordinate system for the ground data?

Comment: @Radek -- Your "nominal" map scale is whatever is stated on the map. If the map (or *any* map) covers a *large* area, however, then there is distortion, ie, the actual scale changes throughout the map. Such a topic is *map projections*. It seems that you really should be asking several separate questions.

Comment: I think I got this in mind. I was intentionally choosing maps of small regions to have the influence of distortion as small as it could be and I would be able to omit the influence of a map projection. The area is about 300km diameter.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine a single map scale from transformation *formulas* alone, only through statistical analysis of the *results* of those transformations. The transformation will alter the scale (distance) between any given two control points on the map and that resulting value may vary from any other control point pair. By analyzing the values from many pairs you can derive a mean/average/etc. global *approximate* scale, but that is its own analysis separate from the transformation process.